# C - Calling a function declared with parameters with no parameters?

Tags: c, function, void, sigaction

I'm trying to understand a code which have the following lines:

```
void terminate_pipe(int);
code code code...
struct sigaction new_Sigiterm;
new_Sigiterm.sa_handler = terminate_pipe;
```

My question are:

- What is the meaning of calling a function like this? Is it going to
  just put `NULL` as the parameter?
- It is void, so `new_Sigiterm.sa_handler` will be `NULL` no matter what?

thanks.

Comment: The function isn't called; a function name without parentheses typically means you're dealing with a function _pointer_. The code in your question simply assigns the address of `terminate_pipe` to the `sa_handler` field in `struct sigaction`. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: I dont think this is the case here. the function is:

void terminate_pipe(int){

*code*

}

its jus the signature of the function. why do you think it is  function pointer?

Comment: It is indeed. Please take a look at the question (and answers) I've linked you to.

Comment: Im sorry, im a java programmer and im very confused now. the sa_handler field is... a function field? and the code is "overriding" it?

Comment: As far as I know, Java really doesn't have anything similar, but in C# the equivalent would be delegates. In general the `sa_handler` field of `struct sigaction` contains an _address_ of a function, so you can call that function at any time. `new_Sigiterm.sa_handler = terminate_pipe;` simply causes that field to point at `terminate_pipe`.

Comment: i could name the function in any name? or i am overriding the specific function "terminate_pipe" of sa_handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new_Sigiterm.sa_handler` is most likely a pointer that points to a function. By running

```
new_Sigiterm.sa_handler = terminate_pipe;
```

It's similar to saying

```
new_Sigiterm.sa_handler = &terminate_pipe;
```

(Like in pointers). This is not running the function, it's just making a pointer that points to the function, if you "run" the pointer, the pointed function will run.

This is how to declare function pointer:

```
void function(int x);

int main()
{
    //Pointer to function
    void (*foo) (int);

    //Point it to our function
    foo = function;

    //Run our pointed function
    foo(5);
}
```

[More info about function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Code like this assignment is setting a handler (sometimes called a **function pointer**): Basically, the address of the function to run, at a given time.

The syntax for this in C is to name the function, but don't put `()` on the end. That returns the address of the function.

```
new_Sigiterm.sa_handler = terminate_pipe;
```

Comment: Note that you could also do `&terminate_pipe`; no difference in this case.

Comment: sa_handler field is a place where the address of the function can be put.

Comment: Im sorry, im a java programmer and im very confused now. the sa_handler field is... a function field? and the code is "overriding" it?

Comment: Correct.  You are changing the address that the program execution goes to.

Comment: At some stage, the execution of the program will look at the variable  new_Sigterm.sa_handler.  Hopefully that code will check for obviously wrong values (like NULL, or 0 (which are the same thing)).  If there is a function to call (or something that looks like a function), then that function will be called.  Hope it's not pointing to invalid memory somewhere :)  Welcome to C.

Answer (score 0):

1. `void terminate_pipe(int);` is not calling of function it is [Forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of function.
2. In `new_Sigiterm.sa_handler` `sa_handler` is a [Function Pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer).